# JOIN FETCH on @ManyToMany relationship produce N + 1 queries

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In my application, I have the following `@Entity` which contains a `@ManyToMany` relationship.

```
@Entity(name="CommonStaff")
@Table(name="staff")
@Getter @Setter @FieldNameConstants
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Staff implements Serializable {
    ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade={ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="staff_language",
               joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="username", referencedColumnName="username") },
               inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="language_code", referencedColumnName="code") })
    private Set<Language> languages = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}

@Entity(name="CommonLanguage")
@Table(name="language")
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Language implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NaturalId
    private String code;
    private String name;
    @Column(name="short_name")
    private String shortName;
    private String description;
    @Column(name="order_id")
    private Integer orderId;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(this.getCode());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other)
            return true;

        if (!(other instanceof Language))
            return false;

        Language that = (Language) other;
        return Objects.equals(that.getCode(), this.getCode());
    }
}
```

In the `@Repository`, I created the following method to fetch `languages` eagerly.

```
@Query(value="SELECT S"
       + "    FROM CommonStaff S"
       + "    JOIN FETCH S.languages"
       + "    WHERE S.userId = :userId")
Staff find(String userId);
```

I created the following method in a `@Controller` to test the query.

```
Staff staff = staffRepo.find(userId);
if (staff != null) {
    System.out.println(staff.getName());
    staff.getLanguages().forEach(language -> System.out.println(language.getName()));
}
```

What I'm seeing in the console is as following.

```
2020-04-18 18:41:02,394 DEBUG [http-nio-9000-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL   : 
    /* SELECT
        S    
    FROM
        CommonStaff S    
    JOIN
        FETCH S.languages    
    WHERE
        S.userId = :userId */ select
            staff0_.id as id1_24_0_,
            language2_.id as id1_9_1_,
            staff0_.email as email2_24_0_,
            staff0_.name as name3_24_0_,
            staff0_.username as username4_24_0_,
            staff0_.is_active as is_activ5_24_0_,
            staff0_.address as address6_24_0_,
            staff0_.biometric_id as biometri7_24_0_,
            staff0_.card_number as card_num8_24_0_,
            language2_.code as code2_9_1_,
            language2_.description as descript3_9_1_,
            language2_.name as name4_9_1_,
            language2_.order_id as order_id5_9_1_,
            language2_.short_name as short_na6_9_1_,
            languages1_.username as username1_25_0__,
            languages1_.language_code as language2_25_0__ 
        from
            staff staff0_ 
        inner join
            staff_language languages1_ 
                on staff0_.username=languages1_.username 
        inner join
            language language2_ 
                on languages1_.language_code=language2_.code 
        where
            staff0_.username=?
2020-04-18 18:41:02,395 TRACE [http-nio-9000-exec-2] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder   : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [90000010]
2020-04-18 18:41:02,411 DEBUG [http-nio-9000-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL   : 
    /* load com.ft.common.db.customer.domain.Language */ select
        language0_.id as id1_9_0_,
        language0_.code as code2_9_0_,
        language0_.description as descript3_9_0_,
        language0_.name as name4_9_0_,
        language0_.order_id as order_id5_9_0_,
        language0_.short_name as short_na6_9_0_ 
    from
        language language0_ 
    where
        language0_.code=?
2020-04-18 18:41:02,411 TRACE [http-nio-9000-exec-2] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder   : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [LAN_ENG]
2020-04-18 18:41:02,420 DEBUG [http-nio-9000-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL   : 
    /* load com.ft.common.db.customer.domain.Language */ select
        language0_.id as id1_9_0_,
        language0_.code as code2_9_0_,
        language0_.description as descript3_9_0_,
        language0_.name as name4_9_0_,
        language0_.order_id as order_id5_9_0_,
        language0_.short_name as short_na6_9_0_ 
    from
        language language0_ 
    where
        language0_.code=?
2020-04-18 18:41:02,420 TRACE [http-nio-9000-exec-2] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder   : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [LAN_MAL]
Edgar Rey Tann
English
Malay
```

From my understanding, `JOIN FETCH` or `LEFT JOIN FETCH` should help me get rid of the last 2 queries but they both didn't work. I couldn't find any viable solutions during my research. I'd be very grateful if you could point me in a direction.

Comment: Add Language class also and use `left join fetch`.

Comment: @AbinashGhosh: This is a uni-directional relationship. In `Language` class, I don't define any kinds of relationship. I also tried `LEFT JOIN FETCH`, result is the same :(

Comment: Try to use equals and hashcode in Language , may JPA can't identify them, https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: @AbinashGhosh: Thanks for the hint. I actually do have `equals` and `hashCode` on all of my entities. I filter out those codes to shorten my question :). I updated my question to include the methods :)

Comment: @Mr.J4mes have you found a solution for this problem?

Comment: I've ran into the same problem, but after a few hours of research and debug I've figured out, that n+1 in this case happens, because fetched entity is `Serialiazable`. If it's `Serialiazable`, hibernate triggers n+1 queries for eager loading, though the whole result set is loaded in first query. I think the solution could be in restructuring the schema, and using primary key in entities associations to remove the Serializable.

Comment: @aleshka-batman Thanks for dropping a comment to update me brother :). I tried to remove `Serializable` from my entity class but I got an exception from Hibernate `ClassCastException: class com...Staff cannot be cast to class java.io.Serializable (com...Staff is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.io.Serializable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org...ManyToOneType.hydrate(ManyToOneType.java:188)
    at org...EntityType.nullSafeGet(EntityType.java:272)
    at org..AbstractEntityPersister.initializeLazyPropertiesFromDatastore(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1271)`

Comment: @aleshka-batman if you have more details to share about your solution (including some exceptions you might have run into), I'd appreciate a detailed answer for my post :D

Comment: @Mr.J4mes yeah, you got the error with Serializable because you joined Staff and Language on code column. If you could join it with primary key column(id), then you wouldn't get Serializable error and Hibernate wouldn't create subqueries. I haven't found any explanation for this, but it's the way how it works.

Comment: @aleshka-batman thanks for the info. I didn't know join by non-primary key column requires `Serializable` until you mentioned :)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the entity is already in the first level cache or also in the second level cache. Try using `entityManager.clear()` before calling `find()`